# Breaking single large raster into NumPyArrays using arcpy memory error

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator, numpy, error-010240

I'm trying to run raster calculator on a large raster file using the following approach : http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm, but I seem to run into memory errors.

I've used `psutil` and `sys.getsizeof()` to figure out that Python grows in memory usage each iteration at the `myData` line even though this object does not accumulate memory. It appears that Python is not releasing this memory and thus eventually maxes out its allocated memory.

I could research increasing memory allocation to Python, but think that there's got to be an easy way to get Python to release that precious memory. Here's the error code, but because I get it when Python reaches 1.4 GB RAM in task manager I think it's a memory issue. 
 `RuntimeError: ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to blockraster\blockprocessingrdb22_191.tif with output format TIFF.`

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
#check out license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
import os

# Loop over data blocks and reclass large raster
lake_elev = arcpy.sa.Raster(<LARGE RASTER>)
fileout = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),r"blockraster\blockprocessingrdb22.tif")

#settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = lake_elev
arcpy.env.cellSize = lake_elev

filelist = []
blockno = 0
blocksize = 1024

for x in range(0, lake_elev.width, blocksize):
    for y in range(0, lake_elev.height, blocksize):

        # Lower left coordinate of block (in map units)
        mx = lake_elev.extent.XMin + x * lake_elev.meanCellWidth
        my = lake_elev.extent.YMin + y * lake_elev.meanCellHeight
        # Upper right coordinate of block (in cells)
        lx = min([x + blocksize, lake_elev.width])
        ly = min([y + blocksize, lake_elev.height])
        #   noting that (x, y) is the lower left coordinate (in cells)

        #memory intensive operation
        myData = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(lake_elev, arcpy.Point(mx, my), lx-x, ly-y, nodata_to_value=-999)

        # Convert data block back to raster
        myRasterBlock = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myData, arcpy.Point(mx, my),
                                                 lake_elev.meanCellWidth,
                                                 lake_elev.meanCellHeight)


        # PROCESS DATA BLOCK -----------------------------
        # convert elevations to liklihoods 
        myRasterBlock = Con(myRasterBlock<176.87, 0.9, Con((myRasterBlock >=176.87) & (myRasterBlock< 178.58), 0.8, Con((myRasterBlock >=178.58) & (myRasterBlock < 182.37), 0.7, Con((myRasterBlock >=182.37) & (myRasterBlock < 212.11), 0.6, 0.4))))
        # Save on disk temporarily as 'filename_#.ext'
        filetemp = ('_%i.' % blockno).join(fileout.rsplit('.',1))
        myRasterBlock.save(filetemp)

        # Maintain a list of saved temporary files
        filelist.append(filetemp)
        blockno += 1

# Mosaic temporary files
arcpy.Mosaic_management(';'.join(filelist[1:]), filelist[0])
if arcpy.Exists(fileout):
    arcpy.Delete_management(fileout)
arcpy.Rename_management(filelist[0], fileout)

# Remove temporary files
for fileitem in filelist:
    if arcpy.Exists(fileitem):
        arcpy.Delete_management(fileitem)

# Release raster objects from memory
del myRasterBlock
del lake_elev
```

Comment: Not sure which version of Arc you are using. But do you have 64 bit background processing installed and enabled?http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm

Comment: 1.2-1.4Gb is all the heap available on a 32-bit architecture process.  There is also a 4Gb size limit to the TIFF file format, so moving to a 64-bit platform might not gain you much headroom.

Comment: @F_Kellner I'm running Arc 10.3 32-bit. I needed the 32 bit version to interact with Anaconda and other Python packages.

Comment: Currently desktop is only a 32 bit program that can be run on 64 bit machines. There is an add-on in the installation of 10.3 that allows you to access your 64bit environment (provided you are on a 64bit machine) through python scripting and the Arcpy library. This would allow you greater in memory than you are currently getting. This add-on it installs a 64bit version of Python on your machine. Not all packages are in this installation but I'm quite certain Numpy in a 64bit version is. Look at the link I provided in my first comment.

Comment: @Luke that looks like enough for an answer